# JSONDecodeError : Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Tags: json, python-3.x, openai-api

[enter image description here][1]I'm working on colab with an API in Python that returns a response as a list of strings. When I try to add an additional item to this list, I encounter a JSONDecodeError.
[enter image description here][2]

```
prompt = (
    "What colors of uniforms are worn by the teams playing in this match?",
    "Return the result in the form of a python list: [], .",
    "Replace the values in '<>' with the names of the colors.",
    "notalk;justgo"
)
response = prompt_image(api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, images=[frame], prompt=prompt)
print(response)
```

````
The teams in the match are wearing uniforms in the colors orange and white. In Python list format:

```python
[ 'orange', 'white' ]
````

```
# Next, I try to add an additional item to the response list:
```

CLASSES = json.loads(response) + ["none"]

```
The print(response) outputs ['orange', 'white'], which is expected. However, when I try to add "none" to this list using json.loads(response) + ["none"], I get the following error:
```

JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)

in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 CLASSES = json.loads(response)

2 frames

/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

```
So I don't really understand why I get this error and how to fixe it


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trrjx.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnwiX.png
```

Comment: If `print(response)` outputs `['orange', 'white']`, then `response` is a *list*, not JSON. You should not call `json.loads` on it. Just do `CLASSES = response + ["none"]`

Comment: It's a string, i have ``` ```python
[ 'orange', 'white' ]
``` ``` and if I tryed ```"CLASSES = response + "['none']"
print(CLASSES)"```, I've got  ``` ```python
[ 'orange', 'white' ]
```['none'] ```

Comment: I see.  That string is not JSON.

Comment: I'm trying to add an image to show what exactly I have, bon i can't

Comment: [link]([https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IEG8NWvtjLEuTCJ-lEgTH6-LHFZl0V3-?usp=drive_link])

Comment: You write in your question *"`print(response)` outputs `['orange', 'white']`, which is expected"*, but that is not true. It prints something that has backtics, the word "python", ...etc. NB: I don't have access to that link.

Comment: Before thinking of adding something to a list, you first have to have the list, and you don't have it. You just have some text. And that text seems to even have something like *"The teams in the match are wearing uniforms ..."*. What is that?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IEG8NWvtjLEuTCJ-lEgTH6-LHFZl0V3-?usp=drive_link

try it again please

Comment: And if it's going to bother, i give you access to the project, if you want. You can help me efficiently like that

Comment: Like I wrote. That is nothing close to JSON. It is English text, that starts with *"The teams in the match are wearing uniforms ..."*.

Comment: So I need to convert them to json